# unable to email using EmailJS without alert

Tags: javascript, html, forms, email

I am trying out EmailJS.com service with the following snippets:
The HTML part:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Daily Report</title>
<script src="https://cdn.emailjs.com/dist/email.min.js"></script>
<script src="tst.js"></script>
<noscript>Please enable JavaScript.</noscript>
</head>
<body onLoad="today()">
<h1 id="today"></h1>
<hr>
<form onSubmit="draft()">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Message</legend>
        <textarea id="shout" rows="2" cols="97">TEST.</textarea><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Email">
    </fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The JavaScript part:

```
var s = new Date().toDateString();
function today() {
    emailjs.init("EMAILJSASSIGNED");
    document.getElementById("today").innerHTML = s;
}
function draft() {
    var m = s + "<br>";
    m += document.getElementById("shout").value + "<br>";
    emailjs.send("EMAILJS_service", "TEMPLATE", {"body":m});
//alert(m);
}
```

I found that the code worked (ie, emailed according to my template specs) only if I add the `alert(m)` line. Seems like `alert` triggers a submit event to execute emailjs.send(). Without the alert, the emailjs.send is "skipped". I don't understand why.

Comment: Can you try using promise so you can get idea about success or error response?

Comment: Unfamiliar with the promise feature. In this case, I need the synchronous pipe: submit the form and then email.

Comment: Any errors in your console?

Comment: No. Of course, with the alert, the content of the textarea is shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the email is not sent without the alert is because once you submit the form the page is reloaded, and the browser doesn't have a chance to complete the emailjs.send() request.

One easy solution is to add "return false" to the onSubmit statement, as follows:

```
<form onSubmit="draft(); return false;">
```

That will prevent the form from being submitted though, so if you do need the form to be submitted to the server you'll need to do this asynchronously, after the promise returned by emailjs.send() is resolved.

You can read more on emailjs.send() syntax, with and without promises here:
https://www.emailjs.com/docs/api-reference/emailjs-send/

Hope this helps!